# Вывод выбранных значений с помощью AjaxBehavior

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Как получить выбранные значения? И в зависимости от того, сколько значений у меня выбрано, изменить label на элементе ? Пытался написать скрипт, но ничего не получилось, т.к. не происходит update label. Т.е. при выборе всех значений, отображается слово "Все". Но когда я убираю все checkbox, оно не исчезает. А если добавить update, то меню с checkbox свернется.

```
   <p:selectCheckboxMenu value="#{managedBean.filterDepartmentIds}" id="emdepartmentList" widgetVar="emdepartmentList"
                                          label="..."
                                          required="#{empty managedBean.filterDepartmentIds}"
                                          rendered="#{managedBean.isCreateMode}"
                                          styleClass="-fill"
                                          multiple = "true">
    <p:ajax update="toolTipFade"/>
    <p:ajax process="@this" update="test1" event="toggleSelect"
            oncomplete="if (PF('emdepartmentList').inputs.filter(':checked').length === #{managedBean.departmentList.size()}){
                                  PF('emdepartmentList').label.text('#{msg['all']}');
                                   }  else {
                                    PF('emdepartmentList').label.text('...');

                                    }"/>
```

Использую Primefaces 5.3. Обновить до более новой версии не могу, ввиду определенных обстоятельств.

Comment: Можно пример с серверной стороной.

Comment: HardCode также принимается

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен добавлением

```
<p:ajax process="@this" event="change"/>
```